# Django ModelForm iterate through MultipleChoiceField Values and process on POST

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

**Level**: Absolute Beginner, trying to build an app to perform some db operation through web UI

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class MysqlUser(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    environment = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from onboard_app.models import MysqlUser


class MysqlUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CHOICES = (
                ('test', 'Test'),
                ('develop', 'Develop'),
                ('staging', 'Staging'),
               )

    environment = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = MysqlUser
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'environment')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from onboard_app.serializers import MysqlUserSerializer
from rest_framework import generics

from onboard_app.forms import MysqlUserForm
from onboard_app.models import MysqlUser
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView


class MysqlCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MysqlUser
    form_class = MysqlUserForm
    template_name = 'mysqluser_form.html'
    success_url = '/mysql/user/add/'
```

**mysqluser_form.html**

```
{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}

{% block title %}MyApp{% endblock %}



{%  block content %}

    <h1>MySQL User Access</h1>
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Grant Access">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

I'm trying to get Value(s) of field or MultipleChoiceFiled `environment` after the user Form Submit, and loop through the entered values to perform some action. I have been trying this for long, still can't figure out how. I don't want to process anything in the frontend html. I'm thinking it has to be processed in the Views but not sure how to get the values of the field and loop over.

Any examples or any django concepts to look into will help me a lot. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have already done so, I recommend going through Django docs on class-based views (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/) to get an overview of how the whole thing works.

So after you submit a form, a `post()` method of your view is called. `CreateView` provides a default implementation, which validates the user input using the `MysqlUserForm` you have provided and then creates an instance of `MysqlUser` and redirects to the `success_url`.

If you want to add more logic, you need to overwrite the `post()` method (or some other method, called by `post()`, in particular, the `form_valid` method) and put your logic there. To get a complete sense of how things work, I recommend you to read through the CreateView, BaseCreateView, ProcessFormView, and ModelFormMixin source code, although the inheritance looks a bit complicated (and it is). More to that, I really advise you to walk through the request processing from the `View.dispatch` method all way to the `form_valid` method using the debugger and see how things really work. Trust me, it will really contribute to your development skills improvement and understanding. Actually, I've discovered the `form_valid` method to write this answer by reading the source code (I use rest-framework nowadays and don't remember a lot about Django views).

So, what you need is

```
class MysqlCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MysqlUser
    form_class = MysqlUserForm
    template_name = 'mysqluser_form.html'
    success_url = '/mysql/user/add/' 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        environment = form.cleaned_data['environment']
        # insert your code here
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

P.S. A good IDE like a PyCharm is really much much more convenient to read source code, jump to relevant parts and **debug** than any text editor and PDB debugger.